# How to correct Knapsack compiling error MiniZinc?

Tags: knapsack-problem, minizinc

What can I do for correcting errors in the following program

```
item= record( int: id,  profit, weight);

set of item: All_Items ;

int :Max_Capacity;

var set of item: Selected_Items;
```

I have the following code for solving knapsack in MiniZinc, but it has many errors.

```
constraint sum([holds(X in Selected_Items)*X.weight | X in All_Items])=< Max_Capacity;

constraint Selected_Items >= All_Items;

maximize
sum([holds(S in Selected_Items)*S.profit |S in All_Items]);
```

Errors List

> ```
> Compiling knapsack1.mzn
> C:/Program Files/MiniZinc IDE (bundled)/examples/knapsack1.mzn:3.7-12:
> item= record( int: id,  profit, weight);
>
>       ^^^^^^
> Error: syntax error, unexpected record
> C:/Program Files/MiniZinc IDE (bundled)/examples/knapsack1.mzn:11.45:
> constraint sum([holds(X in Selected_Items)*X.weight | X in All_Items])=< Max_Capacity;
>
>                                             ^
> Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ]
> C:/Program Files/MiniZinc IDE (bundled)/examples/knapsack1.mzn:15.1-8:
> maximize
>
> ^^^^^^^^
> Error: syntax error, unexpected maximize, expecting end of file
>
> Process finished with non-zero exit code 1
> Finished in 89msec
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although MiniZinc currently does not contain any record-types (read struct like types), they are a possibility for the future. To prevent breaking models in the future, the word `record` is therefore already a reserved keyword and can not be used in as an identifier in your model. Changing the name from `record` to something else will fix your problem.

Comment: Dear Dekker1, Very thanks. Could you please guide me what should I replace instead of record?

Comment: in this link https://www.minizinc.org/downloads/doc-0.8.1/zinc-spec.pdf  page 15 is described about record , but I dont underestand

Comment: There is no full replacement for the record-type in MiniZinc. You have to split your record into multiple variables. Note that the specification you are linking to is the Zinc specification. MiniZinc is a different language from Zinc, which has been deprecated, and doesn't support all features that Zinc supported. MiniZinc takes a more minimal approach.